# Integration Runtime with TTL not helping with Cluster startup time

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I have a pipeline with Foreach loop with in which I have a Dataflow task, that runs on a integration runtime I have setup with 10 min time to live. When I triggered the pipeline with three files (i.e the Dataflow task within the Foreach would execute three times) I see that the cluster startup time remains almost the same (4-6 minutes) for each dataflow execution. I assumed the IR with 10 min TTL would reduce the cluster startup time substantially (for at least the second or third execution) but it doesn't seem that way.
Not sure if I am missing a setup/configuration on the pipeline or IR, or if this is intended behavior. any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When using a ForEach w/Dataflow activity in ADF, if you wish to take advantage of shortened cluster start-up times, you must set the ForEach to execute iterations sequentially. Allow the ForEach to execute in parallel will fire-up new clusters for every iteration even if you have a TTL set on the Azure IR.

Comment: The for each loop seems to be executing sequentially when I look at the monitoring. I see from the monitoring that the dataflows are being executed one after the other after completion of the prior one. Let me know if I am looking at this wrong.

Comment: I will set the sequential to true and see if that improves the cluster time.

Comment: Logged back in today to check, Sequential was set to True for the ForEach, so not sure what's causing the clusters to spin up every time the dataflows executes

Comment: I encounter the same problem. I have a pipeline composed from subpipelines that run sequentially. Some of these subpipelines run data flows with the same IR (30 min TTL) ... but all the data flows are taking 5 minutes to acquire compute.

Comment: The activities must be scheduled to execute within that 30 min TTL, must use the same Azure IR, and must run sequentially. If you try to schedule data flow activities at the same time, ADF will have to spin-up a new cluster to accommodate your request. If you feel all of those conditions are being met, please open an Azure support case so that we can have engineering dig into the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Microsoft added a check box in the Integration Runtime creation process...

[image]

Comment: You'll still need to execute your data flow activities in parallel to "reuse" the cluster during TTL. Otherwise, running in parallel, ADF will have to spin-up additional clusters, each with a 5-min cold startup time because Databricks does not support Scala executors running in parallel.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT this method is only recommended for the execution of data flow activities in sequence.

Comment: Yes, I meant to type "You'll still need to execute your data flow activities in **sequence**"